# Where clause based on another query in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 tables in my database called Jobs, JobApplications, Candidates.

here they are.

**Jobs**

```
    JobId  | JobTitle
    ---------------------------
    2115   | Software Engineer
    2154   | Accountant
    4562   | Sales Manager
    4569   | Civil Engineer
```

**JobApplications**

```
    JobApplicationId  | CandidateId | JobId
    ---------------------------
    8845              | 1120        | 2154
    8912              | 1120        | 4569        
    9120              | 1555        | 2115
    9450              | 1899        | 2115
    9458              | 1991        | 4569
    9488              | 1889        | 4569
```

**Candidates**

```
    CandidateId | Email
    ----------------------------
    1120        | can1@mail.com
    1555        | can2@mail.com
    1889        | can3@mail.com
    1991        | can4@mail.com
```

What I want: A table with candidates and jobIds based on their previous applications.
Ex: if someone has applied for the "software engineer" job position, I need the all other jobs with title "software engineer" except the applied job to a table along with candidateId.

Is there any way to achieve this using SQL?

Can anybody help me?

The expected output would be like below

```
    CandidateId | Suggest_jobId
    ------------------------------
    1120        | 3565
    1120        | 8956
    1120        | 4565
    1889        | 8965
    1889        | 4568
```

So single candidate may have multiple job suggestions.

Comment: if someone has applied for the "software engineer" job position, I need the all other jobs with title "software engineer"  didn't understand this logic can you please elaborate

Comment: I need get all the jobs which are matching to there previous jobs by jobs title.basically I need to suggest new jobs to candidates based on their previous applications

Comment: Can you provide an example of the result that you want?

Comment: The previous applications are stored under JobApplications and new jobs are stored under Jobs

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can make use of a simple `CTE` to do the job

```
 WITH cte AS 
 (
     SELECT j.JobId,
            j.JobTitle,
            ja.CandidateId 
     FROM JobApplications ja
     JOIN Jobs j ON j.JobId=ja.JobId  
 )
 SELECT j.JobTitle,
        c.CandidateId 
 FROM Jobs j
 JOIN cte c ON j.JobTitle like CONCAT('%',c.JobTitle,'%') AND c.JobId!=j.JobId
```

Comment: Thanks! this answer is good. Can we get the this without exact job title matching. as example. if someone has applied for "software engineer" he should get job suggestions with job title like "Senior Software Engineer", "Java Software engineer", "UI/UX Software Engineer".

Answer (score 0):

I have simple and basic solution for you. I have used table function to split applied jobs first. Then I used these results to find similarity using Sanal Sunny's script.

The table function creation script:

```
CREATE  FUNCTION [dbo].[Tbl_Fn_Split](
    @InputText VARCHAR(8000) 
  , @Delimiter VARCHAR(8000) = ' ' -- delimiter that separates items
) RETURNS @List TABLE (Result VARCHAR(8000))

BEGIN
DECLARE @aResult VARCHAR(8000)
WHILE CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@InputText,0) <> 0
BEGIN
    SELECT
        @aResult=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@InputText,1,CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@InputText,0)-1))),
        @InputText=RTRIM(LTRIM(SUBSTRING(@InputText,CHARINDEX(@Delimiter,@InputText,0)+LEN(@Delimiter),LEN(@InputText))))

    IF LEN(@aResult) > 0
        INSERT INTO @List SELECT @aResult
    END

    IF LEN(@InputText) > 0
        INSERT INTO @List SELECT @InputText 

    RETURN

END
```

The finding similarity script which is based on Sanal Sunny's answer:

```
 WITH cte AS 
 (
     SELECT j.JobId,
            j.JobTitle,
            ja.CandidateId,
            A.Result
     FROM JobApplications ja
     JOIN Jobs j ON j.JobId=ja.JobId  
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT * FROM DBO.[Tbl_Fn_Split](j.JobTitle,' ')) A
 )
 SELECT DISTINCT c.CandidateId
        ,j.JobId
        ,j.JobTitle
 FROM Jobs j
 JOIN cte c ON j.JobTitle LIKE '%'+c.Result+'%'AND c.JobId!=j.JobId
```